# navController.navigate() not working in lambda function

Tags: android, android-fragments

On button click I need to perform one POST request, after that open fragment with loaded from network bundle.

Now I am testing without bundle, but `navigate` method does not work, when it is in my network handler.

```
fun changeFragmentToMessages() {
    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_loginFragment_to_messagesFragment)
}


private fun loginButtonClicked(v:View) {
    val login = inputLogin.text.toString()
    val password = inputPassword.text.toString()

    Fuel
        .post(ReqUtils.getUri("loadchats"))
        .body(
            JSONObject(
                mapOf(
                    "login" to login,
                    "password" to password
                )
            ).toString()
        )
        .header("content-type", "application/json")
        .response {
            request, response, result ->
            Log.d("HTTP", "Got login response")
            changeFragmentToMessages()
        }
}
```

I can see "Got login response" in logcat, so the lambda is called.
Also, if we move `changeFragmentToMessages()` out of lambda, before `Fuel...` call, everything works as it has to - fragment opens on button click.

Comment: `NavController` obviously is `null`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler, I checked and navController is not null. Moreover, I introduced a global variable to put there value from findNavController() method on creating view, and if it was null, wouldn't I have got an NPE or at least need to make safe call using "?"?

Comment: Even when it's not `null`, you're not going to update the UI thread from a background thread.

Comment: @MartinZeitler, how can I execute this task on main thread, after I made an async http request?